# How to reference a selector with special characters in CSS

Tags: css

I’m attempting to edit the Steam Deck virtual keyboard using CSS Editor. I’m able to change some individual keys, but not the keys with special characters in their selector.

For example, in the original file, the style rule for the “(“ key is:

`.Spectrum .virtualkeyboard_KeyboardKey_2KhPX.KeyTheme_\({color:#ffffff;background-color:#1B6E14}`

When I put that line in my CSS file, it doesn't read the "(" as part of the selector, so none of my changes go through.

I’ve tried removing the “\”, which worked for the “`" key but not the other keys. I've also tried replacing "(" with the hex code, 28.

Answer (score 0):

You need that additional `\` to escape the characters that are not standard in CSS class names.

If you want to be exact sure, you can make use of [`CSS.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape_static) method to find out the class names that is valid to be placed in your CSS stylesheets, for example: `CSS.escape('KeyTheme_({color:#ffffff;background-color:#1B6E14})')` (I have also added a JavaScript in the sample below to showcase this functionality)

```js
// Just to showcase the functionality of CSS.escape, doesn't need to be included in your code
console.log(CSS.escape('KeyTheme_({color:#ffffff;background-color:#1B6E14})'));
```

```css
.KeyTheme_\(\{color\:\#ffffff\;background-color\:\#1B6E14\}\) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="KeyTheme_({color:#ffffff;background-color:#1B6E14})">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I've tried leaving the '\' in, as it is in my original post. Should I be adding another '\' somewhere else?

Comment: Hi @Dan, can you update your question above to include the CSS / HTML of that particular element you are trying to override? It seems like the code might be missing some characters here and there.

Comment: I'm not able to find the HTML that uses this CSS but I've double checked and the code in my post is exactly as it appears in the original CSS.

Comment: Hi @Dan, in that case you will need 3 \ instead, use the CSS.escape function to find out

Comment: I tried changing it from ‘.KeyTheme_\({…}’ to ‘.KeyTheme_\\\({…}’ and I still don’t see the changes.

Comment: @Dan Change it to `.KeyTheme_\\\({…}` instead

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in my comment. That is what I changed it to.